# php clone not working how I expected

Tags: php, mysql, clone

Trying to construct a simple datagrid from a mySQL db.

The database class I am using to connect returns the result set as an object. I want to clone this object so that i can use the getNext() method to get the headers of the table without moving the pointer forward to drop the first row returned. I expect this to be simple as cloning the result set so that I now have 2 object that are identical. then returning the headers in one object while leaving the other object untouched.

This however has proven to be harder then I thought. Perhaps I am not using clone properly so if you can help please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Below is the code:

```
        function gethtmlTable($database, $table)
            {
                $db = new DB_Connection();
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table;";
                $result = $db->query($sql,$database);
                $tabelheader = clone $result;
                $tablerows = clone $result;
                if (!$result) die($db->getError());
                if ($result->getNumRows() == 0) die('No Results');

                $count = $tabelheader->getNumRows();
                $html = "<table><th>Select</th>";

                // echo "<pre>".var_dump($result)."</pre>";    
                foreach($tabelheader->getNext() as $k => $v){
                       $html .="<th>".$k."</th>";
                }
                while($count > 0){ 
                    $row = $tablerows->getNext();      
                    $html .= "<tr>";
                    $html .= "<td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox".$count."' name=checkbox".$count." class ='styled' value='checked'></td>";

                    foreach($row as $k => $v){
                            $html .="<td>".$v."</td>";
                    }

                    //foreach($result->getNext() as $k => $v){
                    //   $html .="<td>".$v."</td>";
                    //}
                    $html .="</tr>";
                    $count--;
                 }
                $html .="</table>";
                echo $html;

            }
```

When I run this function I get back a table with headers and a select box but the first row is always missing.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a solution than a direct answer, but you don't need to clone your object. Instead, you can change your `while` loop a bit and just use the `$result` from your query:

```
do
{
  // do the stuff you are doing now except for fetching a new row


  // at the end:
  $count--;
  $row = $result->getNext();
}
while ($count > 0)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for the suggestion. I didn't even think about using a do - while instead of over complicating it with clone :)

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the $result object does not mean that you can read from 2 different datasources.

It is still **one datasource** underlying, with one cursor!

So this line:

```
  foreach($tabelheader->getNext() as $k => $v) {
      $html .="<th>".$k."</th>";
  }
```

Will actually fetch the first record from the datasource, and

```
while($count > 0) { 
    $row = $tablerows->getNext();
    ...
```

will fetch then from row 2 and futher!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the suggestions I realized I was over complicating this :D

Here is the solution for anyone out there who is trying to do the same

```
        function gethtmlTable($database, $table)
        {
            $db = new DB_Connection();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table;";
            $result = $db->query($sql,$database);
            //$tabelheader = clone $result;
            //$tablerows = clone $result;
            if (!$result) die($db->getError());
            if ($result->getNumRows() == 0) die('No Results');

            $count = $result->getNumRows();
            $html = "<table><th>Select</th>";
            $row = $result->getNext();

            foreach($row as $k => $v){
                   $html .="<th>".$k."</th>";
            }

            do {
                $html .= "<tr>";
                $html .= "<td><input type='checkbox' id='checkbox".$count."' name=checkbox".$count." class ='styled' value='checked'></td>";

                foreach($row as $k => $v){
                    $html .="<td>".$v."</td>";
                }

                $count--;    
                $row = $result->getNext();
            }
            while ($count > 0);
```